# Android support-v4:22.0.0 Not downloading to correct location?

Tags: android, libraries, android-sdk-manager

I'm using com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0  which requires: support-v4:22.0.0. Ok no problem right? -- so I download it via SDK Manager:

[image]

Now, Android Studio still reports that it cannot find com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0:

Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0.
         Searched in the following locations:
             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
             file:/C:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
             file:/C:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar
             file:/C:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.pom
             file:/C:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/22.0.0/support-v4-22.0.0.aar

So then I go to the location ( C:/android-sdk/extras/**google**/m2repository/com/android/support  )  to see for myself, and of course its not there. Now I know the download suceeded, so I search my drive for it. Turns out the SDK manager downloaded it to: C:\android-sdk\extras**android**\support\v4  instead. So I tried to import the jar file contained in that folder to my project but that did not work. How do I get around this?

Comment: In your screenshot, it's the 22.2 which is downloaded, not the 22.0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Android Support Library" entry in the SDK Manager is primarily for Eclipse users. You are using Android Studio, so what matters is the "Android Support Repository", which you have not updated in the SDK Manager.